# How to prevent Magento admin url being indexed from Google?

Tags: magento-1.7, robots.txt

Is there any safe way apart from the *robots.txt* to prevent the Magento admin url being indexed by Google.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways

**The first way to use robots.txt in a safe way:**

I didn't try it but it should work.

suppose you admin url is localhost.com/admin . Create a sub folder called secret, then a sub folder called admin.

the structure is /secret/admin. Put the **robots.txt** file inside secret and copy the index.php to admin folder.

Edit the path in index.php . Then change the admin url in magento to localhost.com/secret/admin . I prefer to change it from the local.xml not from the back-end.

**The second way to use .htaccess file to stop bots. It will be something like that:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/.* - [R=403,L]
```

**Third way**: to protect it with a password ( I prefer this way ). Because it is simple and will block the bots and users who does not know the password.